# dynamic segments is not working

Tags: ember-cli

I have setup the following route in router.js:

```
this.route('reports',{path:'/reports/:report_name'}, function(){

});
```

I have following link setup in on of the hbs file:

```
{{#link-to 'reports' 'eod-2015'}}EOD 2015{{/link-to}}
```

in `app/route/reports/index.js`

```
model: function(params) {
  console.log(params);
}
```

and I am getting {} as a result, how can I find report_name in my index.js route in app/route/reports folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to access param in `app/route/reports/index.js` you should access it in `app/route/reports.js`.

See [demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/8e4029e93a85f3a08826?openFiles=reports.route.js%2Capplication.template.hbs&route=%2Freports%2Feod-2015)

Comparison:

> Inside reports.js file: Object {report_name: "eod-2015"}
>
> Inside index.js file: Object {}

If you would like to access `reports` params inside `reports.index` route you could do:

```
model(params) {
  const parentParams = this.paramsFor('reports');
  console.log('Accessing reports.js from index.js:', parentParams);
}
```